# How to make maintaince document for a website?

Tags: css, xhtml, documentation

How to make maintenance document for a website? I've created a site using XHTML ,CSS, jQuery etc. it's big site.

Now i have to write a maintenance document for a site for if any changes comes in future related to design, content and functionality then those things will be handled by someone else.

How and what should i keep in maintenance document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your maintenance document should contain a **high-level design** of what each file contains and the general code structure of the project.

For example, if you wrote some **javascript to handle certain events**, document those and how they interact with the page.

You should also document any **logical groupings** you've made. If a folder contains all the XHTML for a certain topic, write those down.

Also give a **brief explanation of how you used CSS to layout the page**. Which classes are where on the page, and which classes or ids are important.

Comment: +1 Thanks for reply . Do you know any sample link?

Comment: No, I'm just listing off the top of my head what was in the last maintenance doc I wrote.

Comment: What is the mean of "high-level design"? I haven't made design. i just converted PSD into XHTML CSS

Comment: In that case I would just describe the layout and the slices you used.

Answer (score 1):

As for the how, I like to set up a Wiki in such cases, for example [DokuWiki](http://www.dokuwiki.org). They're easy to understand, and in case of DokuWiki there's no database involved, just plain text files.

As to what, (in addition to what Ben S nicely outlines in his answer) I'd cover

- The basic technologies used
- Any client-side libraries used and their versions
- A rundown on the directory structure
- The hosting environment, what is configured where, control panel URLs and the like (never actual passwords)
- Names and contact data of contacts (Tech support, etc.) plus any experiences with them (how best to reach them, phone, mail, etc.)

Comment: Some friend suggested me to make style guide. are style guide and Maintenance doc are same thing?

Comment: @jitendra No. A style guide deals with the design of the site, colours, logos...